# Android Java Webview app: how to open facebook, twitter, linkedin and whatsapp app via my webview app

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview app of my website. On my website i have a plugin installed of facebook, twitter, LinkedIn and whatsapp. But if I want to click on facebook or twitter or linkedin or whatsapp via my webview app on one of the pages because i want to share that page/blog, the apps on my mobile will not open.  How can i make sure my webview app will do that.
see the code below

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);

        webView.setWebChromeClient( new MyWebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient( new webClient());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.hindnc.nl/");
    }

    public class  MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        }
    }

    public class webClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else  {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```